Visual Studio: Error in library imports of springframework. Package does not exist
I was making a little proyect, but when a start with spring libraries i have a problem, VSC mark the "org" like a error.
package pe.pildoras.ioc;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.apache.*;

public class UsoEmpleados {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext contexto = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
     
        System.out.println("todo bien");

    }
    
}

package org.springframework.context.support does not exist
package import org.apache does not exist.

The problem is alwas in the org of the imports.
enter image description here
The proyect compiles without problem, is just the message error.
I have the libraries correctly imported, (without maven or graddle, all manual just to learn).
I tested the same proyect with the same configuration in net beans and there is any problem.
pd: a had a problem with packages too with created classes, but the error desapair after use "clean java languaje server workspace"
package pe.pildoras.ioc;

public class ejemplo {

}

error: Incorrect Package


Maybe check the dependencies, make sure you have properly mentioned required dependencies, in this case it should be 'org.springframework' in pom.xml or build.gradle file.

Thanks, but that does not the problem, I already solved, I disable Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code and the problem is gone.
